# Unity 2019 build for Oculus Go not appearing on device

Tags: unity, android, oculus

My project was building fine in 2018 and showing up on my Go under "unknown sources".

My project builds fine in 2019 and it says it gets installed but it no longer shows up under "unknown sources" or anywhere else that I can see.

I can uninstall using adb - so it's there apparently, but where, and how can I launch it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got it. VR was enabled, Oculus was listed in the dropdown. I needed to unload Oculus and reload it, now it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me that sounds a lot like trying to sideload an Android-App (without oculus sdk) to Oculus Go. It's on there but there is no way to open it.

For troubleshooting:
Could check XRSettings and such, to see if Oculus SDK was deactivated when upgrading your project to 2019?

What happens if you create a new Project in 2019, integrate Oculus SDK and load it onto the GO?